# Permission error moving file after processing in loop in Python

Tags: python, json

I have 3 json files that need to be parsed by python.

file1.jasn
file2.json
file3.json

I have intentionally sabotaged the format in file3.json so it doesn't actually contain correct json formatting.

my code:

```
import os, json, shutil

fileRoot = 'C:/root/python/'
inputFiles = fileRoot + 'input/'
processed_folder = fileRoot + 'processed/'
error_folder = fileRoot + 'error/'

print("processFiles")

print('inputfiles = ' + inputFiles)

if any(File.endswith(".json") for File in os.listdir(inputFiles)):
    json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(inputFiles) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

print('--------------------FILES IN DIRECTORY----------------------')
print(json_files)
print( '--------------------FILE LOOPING----------------------------')

for eachfile in json_files:
    print(eachfile)
    with open((inputFiles + eachfile), 'r') as f:
        try:
            data = json.load(f)
        except :
            shutil.move((inputFiles + eachfile), error_folder)
```

The idea is that if it doesn't parse the JSON, the file should be moved to another folder called 'error'

However, I keep getting errors such as:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Python/input/file3.json' -> 'C:/root/Python/input/file3.json'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the files, and they stay open until the `with` block exits.

As a work-around you can store the files that you want to move in a list:

```
move_to_error = []
move_to_valid = []
for eachfile in json_files:
    print(eachfile)
    with open((inputFiles + eachfile), 'r') as f:
        try:
            data = json.load(f)
            # if we have an exception in the previous line,
            # the file will not be appended to move_to_valid
            move_to_valid.append(eachfile)
        except:
            move_to_error.append(eachfile)
for eachfile in move_to_error:
    shutil.move((inputFiles + eachfile), error_folder)
```

Comment: brilliant, however, if I split the lists by **error_files** and **valid_files**, how do I move the valid files to a valid_files list? so move anything that isn't in error_file list to a valid list for further processing? Hopefully, that makes sense